# Who was King Narishyant?

Tags: puranas

What is the story of the king **Narishyant** the eldest son of **King Marut**?
In Which yuga he was born?
Who was his mother
**Sukesha-** the daughter of Kekaya or **Saindhavi-** the daughter of Sindhuraaj or **Vayushmati-** the daughter of Chediraaj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://hinduonline.co/Scriptures/Puranas/MarkandeyaPurana.html) is a brief mention of King Narishyant in Markandeya Purana.

> Among the eighteen sons of Marut, Narishyant was the eldest. Marut ruled over his kingdom for 70,015 years after which Narishyant succeeded him as the king. Marut went to the forest to do penance. After becoming the king, Narishyant decided to perform a grand Yagya, the like of which had never been accomplished by his ancestors. Narishyant made such huge donations to the Brahmins that it was more than enough for their future generations to come.

Here is Another Source about his mother Sukesha- the daughter of Kekaya or Saindhavi- the daughter of Sindhuraaj or Vayushmati- the daughter of Chediraaj.
[image]